# AW Blog left block not showing

Tags: module, xml, menu

I installed this blog module:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/blog-community-edition-by-aheadworks.html

I tried several options on module configuration, but the left and right menu doesn't appears. Please see the images:
[image: Left menu]
[image: Module configuration]

I move the files from design/frontend/default to design/frontend/my_theme and tried to change the xml file. The original xml file: http://pastebin.com/FGuFfjrY

I tried to change in different ways the line 17 to 24.

Thank you for listening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, the solution is here: http://pastebin.com/2VHY2ZjE

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I imagine Pastebin not go change the link, but I added the <reference name="left">...</refence> block that was in <default>...</default> inside <blog_post_view></blog_post_view> and <blog_index_list></blog_index_list>